# Javascript function only working on single post

Tags: javascript, autorotate

i am trying to do is automatically rotate a ads on my sidebar using this javascript.

```
function run() {
    var prev = $("#pengiklanan a.beriklan:first-child");
    $.unique(prev).each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(i*1000).slideUp(function() {
        $(this).appendTo(this.parentNode).slideDown();
      });
    });
}

window.setInterval(run,19000);
```

AND my ads source on my sidebar is

```
<div id="pengiklanan"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/BelajarSeo" target="_blank" class="beriklan"><h6 class="ohiklan">Iklan Anda</h6><p><em>cepat, ruangan terhad</em></p></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/BelajarSeo" target="_blank" class="beriklan"><h6 class="ohiklan">Iklan Anda</h6><p><em>cepat, ruangan terhad</em></p></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/BelajarSeo" target="_blank" class="beriklan"><h6 class="ohiklan">Iklan Anda</h6><p><em>cepat, ruangan terhad</em></p></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/BelajarSeo" target="_blank" class="beriklan"><h6 class="ohiklan">Iklan Anda</h6><p><em>cepat, ruangan terhad</em></p></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/BelajarSeo" target="_blank" class="beriklan"><h6 class="ohiklan">Iklan Anda</h6><p><em>cepat, ruangan terhad</em></p></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/BelajarSeo" target="_blank" class="beriklan"><h6 class="ohiklan">Iklan Anda</h6><p><em>cepat, ruangan terhad</em></p></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/messages/BelajarSeo" target="_blank" class="beriklan"><h6 class="ohiklan">Iklan Anda</h6><p><em>cepat, ruangan terhad</em></p></a></div>
```

This javascript function is working (rotate a ads on my sidebar) on my single post. But in my homepage, page, category, tags and other page, this javascript not working.

Anyone please... - [my site](http://www.forblogger.net/)

Comment: It seems you did not include jQuery on your page... (Firebug is saying: TypeError: $ is not a function) Try replacing `$` by `jQuery`, this solves it but not sure why...

Comment: there's no need to call `.unique` - jQuery collections are guaranteed unique by the API.

Comment: Hi Jadkik94, thanks for your reply :) . The problem is solved :D

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: @user1620427 Also note there are other similar issues on your website: `TypeError: $.cookie is not a function`. That's maybe because you changed the jQuery version, or there's a missing plugin. Also, if I helped solve your issue, please consider accepting my answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the scripts on your page calls a function `jQuery.noConflict();`. This means that you no longer can reference `jQuery` by `$` to avoid conflicts with some other script.

So you either need to remove that line, but most probably there's a good reason it's there. Or you can replace all your references to `$` by `jQuery`.

I found this using Firebug, which tells you that `$` was not defined. You just needed to know why it wasn't from there.

Comment: Hi jadkik94, your say "replace all your references to $ by jQuery". can i replace my script like below?

`var prev = jQuery("#pengiklanan a.beriklan:first-child");
    jQuery.unique(prev).each(function(i) {
      jQuery(this).delay(i*1000).slideUp(function() {
        jQuery(this).appendTo(this.parentNode).slideDown();
      });
    });
}

window.setInterval(run,19000);`